# Where are the ISOs for disk encryption version of Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, live-usb, encryption

I would like to do a bootable usb key and encrypt the system. This was done before with alternate CDs but it seems that it does not exist anymore. Where are the ISOs that replace the alternate Cds ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mini iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso), aka netinst.

Comment: It looks like one can encript with usual live CDs now...http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail#.UlMMtUHJTzw or http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-13-04-348582.shtml ???